# How to use a cell reference in Field Item pair of GETPIVOTDATA

Tags: excel-formula, pivot-table

I have the below formula to get data from a pivottable

```
GETPIVOTDATA("Sales", $A$4, "[Month].[Month]", "[Month].[Month].&[March]")
```

Now I'm trying to use this formula by replacing March with C13 and the formula looks like this:

```
GETPIVOTDATA("Sales", $A$4, "[Month].[Month]", "[Month].[Month].&[C13]")
```

But it's giving !Ref error. I tried giving &[&C13&] as well. But none are working.

Can someone help me in fixing this?

Comment: How about `GETPIVOTDATA("Sales", $A$4, "[Month].[Month]", "[Month].[Month].&["&C13&"]")`

Comment: Awesome.. it's working. Please post it as answer as well. I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to provide the reference to the cell e.g. `C13` outside the string containing the month reference. Like this:

`GETPIVOTDATA("Sales", $A$4, "[Month].[Month]", "[Month].[Month].&["&C13&"]")`